# Missing part of my query

Tags: php, mysql

ok i was working with someone on this project an he decide to not finish it.. but he deleted part of my query.. can anyone take a guess what it is.. i was not part of this section of the project.....

```
<?PHP 
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
$dbname = "ADLMaster";
$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."<BR>");
mysql_select_db($dbname);


$zoom = '4';
$x_offset = '-162.2200';
$y_offset = '320.2600';
$shownames = 'Yes';
$highlight = '12';

?> 

<html><head><title>Requested Planetary Information</title></head><body link="#FF0000" vlink="#FF0000" alink="#FF0000" text="#C3C3C3" bgcolor="#000000" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<body>
<h2>Requested Planetary Information</h2><p><?php


$sql = "SELECT MIN(xcoord) AS min_x,
               MAX(xcoord) AS max_x,
               MIN(ycoord) AS min_y,MAX(ycoord) as max_y 
          FROM adlPlanet";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);

# Create the extremes
$x_max = $row->max_x;
$x_min = $row->min_x;
$y_max = $row->max_y;
$y_min = $row->min_y;
$x_range = 800;
$y_range = 600;

$x_center = $x_max - $x_min - $x_range;
$y_center = $y_max - $y_min - $y_range;

# Max number of light years that can be jumped.
$jly = 30;


# Now calculate based on cartesian coordinates where the user clicked.
$xcoord = (($mapcoords_x + $x_min + ($x_center / 2))/$zoom) + $x_offset;
$ycoord = -((($mapcoords_y - $y_max + ($y_center / 2))/$zoom) - $y_offset);


$sSQL = <<<EOQ
   SELECT Team.Label Label,
          Planet.PlanetKey PlanetKey, 
          Planet.Climate Climate,
          Planet.Label PlanetLabel,
          Team.ShortLabel ShortLabel,
          Planet.xcoord xcoord,
          Planet.ycoord ycoord
     FROM adlPlanet Planet
LEFT JOIN adlTeam Team on Planet.TeamKey = Team.TeamKey
    WHERE ($xcoord >= xcoord - 3) 
      AND ($xcoord <= xcoord + 3) 
      AND ($ycoord >= ycoord - 3) 
      AND ($ycoord <= ycoord + 3) 
      AND **here is the missing part------------------------->**
EOQ;

echo $sSQL;
echo "<br><br>";


# (add to where if you figure out whats wrong) 
$result = mysql_query($sSQL);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result)
?> 


<strong>Owner:</strong> 
<a href="showowner.php?own=<?php echo $row->ShortLabel; ?>"><?php echo $row['PlanetLabel'] . "(" .$row['ShortLabel'] . ")"; ?></a><br>

<strong>Planet Name:</strong> <?php print $row->PlanetLabel; ?><br>

<strong>Position:</strong> <?php print "$row->xcoord, $row->ycoord"; ?><br>

<strong>Climate:</strong> <?php print $row->Climate; ?><br>

<?php

    # Save planet information.
    $planet = new PlanetData;
    $planet->PlanetKey = $row->PlanetKey;
    $planet->PlanetLabel = $row->PlanetLabel;
    $planet->ShortLabel = $row->ShortLabel;
    $planet->xcoord = $row->xcoord;
    $planet->ycoord = $row->ycoord;



    # Find the nearest jumps.
    $select = "SQRT(POWER($planet->xcoord - xcoord, 2) + POWER($planet->ycoord - ycoord, 2)) AS distance";
    $having = "(distance <= $jly) AND (PlanetKey != $planet->PlanetKey)";
    $result = mysql_db_query("ADLMaster", "SELECT $select FROM adlPlanet HAVING ($having) ORDER BY distance");

?> 

<strong>Nearest Jumps:</strong> 

<?php
    # Print the jumps
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
?> 

<a href="adl_map.php?sidereload=1&x_offset=<?php echo $row->xcoord; ?>&y_offset=<?php echo $row->ycoord; ?>&highlight=<?php echo $row->PlanetKey; ?>" target="map">
<?php
        printf ("%s (%0.2f ly)", $row->Label, $row->distance);
?>
</a>

<?php
    }

?>



</body></html>
```

> below is a sample of the database with
>   out the where on the query.. when i
>   add is back on i get zero results

```
Label   PlanetKey   Climate PlanetLabel ShortLabel  xcoord  ycoord
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    1   Volcanic    A Place ARDC    -125.1800   274.8800
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    2   Arid    Arc-Royal   ARDC    -172.1300   228.7200
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    3   Temperate   Atocongo    ARDC    -172.3900   247.5000
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    4   Tropical    Babaeski    ARDC    -138.7500   310.6100
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    5   Volcanic    Bountiful Harvest   ARDC    -138.4800   263.4100
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    6   Lunar   Deia    ARDC    -177.6000   306.4400
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    7   Industrial  Dustball    ARDC    -105.3600   268.6200
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    8   Tropical    Esteros ARDC    -159.6100   271.2300
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    9   Arctic  Great X ARDC    -185.9500   290.5300
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    10  Volcanic    Koniz   ARDC    -93.3700    262.1000
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    11  Temperate   Kookens Pleasure Pit    ARDC    -166.6500   348.9500
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    12  Temperate   Mkuranga    ARDC    -162.2200   320.2600
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    13  Temperate   Morges  ARDC    -142.6600   286.1000
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    14  Arid    New Exford  ARDC    -138.4800   245.4100
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    15  Arctic  Pasig   ARDC    -166.6500   335.6500
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    16  Tropical    Yeguas  ARDC    -162.4800   284.5300
Arc-Royal Defense Cordon    17  Temperate   Zanderij    ARDC    -179.6900   267.8400
Capallen Confederation  18  Temperate   Aldebaran   CAP 25.0400 -64.9400
Capallen Confederation  19  Arctic  Aldertaine  CAP 45.1200 -192.7300
Capallen Confederation  20  Volcanic    Altorra CAP -2.8700 -265.7600
Capallen Confederation  21  Industrial  Andarmax    CAP -3.3900 -389.9000
Capallen Confederation  22  Industrial  Ares    CAP 96.2400 -175.5200
Capallen Confederation  23  Arid    Bandora CAP 13.3000 -178.9100
Capallen Confederation  24  Lunar   Barras  CAP 21.1200 -357.3000
Capallen Confederation  25  Tropical    Bellatrix   CAP 54.7700 -354.6900
Capallen Confederation  26  Temperate   Bentley CAP -7.0400 -235.7600
Capallen Confederation  27  Volcanic    Betelgeuse  CAP 5.7400  -309.5700
Capallen Confederation  28  Volcanic    Bithnia CAP -19.0400    -179.9500
Capallen Confederation  29  Arid    Boardwalk   CAP -13.8200    -199.2500
Capallen Confederation  30  Arid    Bora    CAP 39.1200 -159.0900
```

Comment: Sorry about being negative, but how can we, total strangers, guess if even you have no idea?

Comment: SO provides help -- we're not here to do the work for you.

Comment: what do u mean do the work for me... all i was asking for was a guess where it says *here is the missing part------------------------->** not asking you to finish the app

Comment: Interesting Query, but as the others said, how can we guess what you were trying to do if you can't?

Comment: It seems to be some type of website where the user clicks somewhere in a bounding box (perhaps an image representing all the planets in the database) and the server returns the distance for the nearest planets to the location which you clicked. The query in question seems to be fetching all the planets within a bounding box that is centered where the user clicked and extends 3 units in every direction.

Comment: The where part of the query is simply filtering out planets that are within a specific bounding box. Could you print out what $xcoord and $ycoord are before the query is executed?

Comment: ok i think i figured it out... he put the extra AND there to throw me off.... i was trying to find the planets within 30 and he had WHERE ($xcoord >= xcoord - 3) 
      AND ($xcoord <= xcoord + 3) 
      AND ($ycoord >= ycoord - 3) 
      AND ($ycoord <= ycoord + 3)  i just had to change 3 to 30... thanks anyways

Comment: Also, these are not real planets.  There seems to be no record of "Capallen" nor "Arc-Royal" in the official planet registry.  Where are you getting your information?

Answer (score 0):

The query appears to be correct. I would guess that the problem is that you are passing in an $xcoord and $ycoord that are outside the area where all the planets are located. Also, $mapcoords_x and $mapcoords_y are never being set.